# Multiplying the loss function of a Keras model by some constant C, and also dividing its learning rate by C

Tags: keras

Is it true that "In Keras, if you multiply the loss function of a model by some constant C, and also divide the learning rate by C, no difference in the training process will be occurred" ?

I have a model implemented by Keras. I define a loss function as:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_est): 
     return something
```

In the first scenario I use an Adam optimizer with learning rate equal to 0.005, and I compile the model with that loss function and optimizer. I fit the model on a set of training data and I observe that its loss falls down from 0.2 to 0.001 in less than 100 epochs.

In the second scenario I change the loss function to:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_est):
    return 1000 * something
```

and the learning rate of the optimizer to 0.000005 . Then I compile the model with the new loss function and optimizer, and see what happens to its loss function.
In my understanding, since the gradient of the new loss is 1000 times of the previous gradient, and the new learning rate is 0.001 times of the previous learning rate, in the second scenario, the loss function should fall down from 200 to 1 in less than 100 epochs. But surprisingly, I observe that the loss function is stuck around 200 and almost does not decrease.

Does anyone have any justifications for that?

Comment: Do the test without changing the learning rate. Chances are that the speed will be the same in both cases. If this is true, then the gradient is probably being normalized before applying the learning rate. (I suggest you use two equal models with the same weights, so you don't be mislead by random factors).

Comment: I believe Adam and other adaptive optimizers expect a loss function of some scale. If you multiply or divide it by a big enough constant they don't work properly anymore. With normal optimizers it should be enough to rescale the learning rate, but with Adam you should probably tune the other hyperparameters as well (beta1 and beta2).
This is only an unverified supposition based on what I'm seeing right now in my model

Comment: @filippo There is gradient normalization in the Adam algorithm (Quote from paper "In Adam, the update rule for individual weights is to scale their gradients inversely proportional to a (scaled) L2 norm of their individual current and past gradients." ) - so the only change that would effect learning is the step size.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use SGD, the result would be what you expect. However, loss scale has no effect on adam. I suggest you to understand those formulas about adam. Therefore, you just changed the learning rate of the network and the learning rate is too small for you network.